# Laravel 5 Nested models with parent relationship

Tags: laravel, model, nested

I am struggling with Laravel 5 nested models with a parent-child relationship. I manage to get the information i need but it takes 8 - 9 queries, and i believe that it should be doable with only 4.

The 3 tables look similar to this:

**Article table**

```
id | title | description | parent_id | user_id
-----------------------------------------------
1  | Some title  | Awes. text  | null  | 1

2  | Child title | Super text  | 1     | 2

3  | Child2title | Super text  | 1     | 1
```

**Comments table**

```
id | article_id | user_id | comment

1  | 1          | 2       | Funny commment
```

**And the Users table**

```
id | name | ... | ...
```

And i have the following models defined:

**Article model**

```
class Article extends Model {

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\User', 'id', 'user_id')->select(array('id', 'name', 'points'));
    }

    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Comment')->with('user');
    }

     public function children()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Article', 'parent_id', 'id')->with('user', 'comments')->select(array('id', 'parent_id', 'description', 'votes', 'updated_at', 'user_id'));
    }

}
```

**Comment model**

```
class Comment extends Model {

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\User', 'id', 'user_id')->select(array('id', 'name', 'points'));
    }

    public function article()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Article');
    }

}
```

**User model**

```
class User extends Model {

    protected $table = 'users';


    protected $fillable = ['name', 'email', 'password', 'points'];


    protected $hidden = ['email', 'role', 'password', 'remember_token'];

}
```

Now I can get the parent article with user and comments (and users from comments) together with all the child articles with again the user that posted the article + all comments with users that posted the comments with the following query:

```
$article = Article::with('user', 'comments', 'children')->findOrFail(1);
```

But it results in 8 queries

```
select * from `articles` where `articles`.`id` = ? limit 1
select `id`, `name`, `points` from `users` where `users`.`id` in (?)
select * from `comments` where `comments`.`article_id` in (?)
select `id`, `name`, `points` from `users` where `users`.`id` in (?, ?, ?)
select `id`, `parent_id`, `description`, `votes`, `updated_at`, `user_id` from `articles` where `articles`.`parent_id` in (?)
select `id`, `name`, `points` from `users` where `users`.`id` in (?, ?, ?, ?)
select * from `comments` where `comments`.`article_id` in (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
select `id`, `name`, `points` from `users` where `users`.`id` in (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

I have tried many things but i keep getting 8 - 9 queries.

I feel like this should be doable with only 4 queries:

- Get parent article
- Get childs articles
- Get comments
- Get users

Am I missing something ?

Comment: Looks about right.  That's how Eloquent's ORM works:  looots of queries.  You might be better off fetch all articles, loading their relations, and then iterating the results and manually folding the children under the parents.

Comment: Ok So I am not doing something absurdly wrong ? Thanks alot for the tip.